# Netbeans Maven project - deploy including dependencies

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

When I clean & build the maven based project in Netbeans the dependencies are not copied to the target folder.

So when I try to run the application on another machine it will not work.

How can I include all dependencies into the /target folder and have them linked so that they will be found when the application runs on another machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a plugin like [`org.codehaus.mojo:appassembler-maven-plugin`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/) to create a distributable programm. This plugin copies all dependencies needed.

Please read the documentation for more information.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Was not so easy to implement it in Netbeans but at the end it worked. I now have nice .sh and .bat scripts that I can run on every machine.